# handling invalid session id

Tags: soap-api, webservices, java

been running a java spring webservice application that runs on on a schedule, but for some reason the enterprise connection occasionally errors out.

```
2017-07-13 07:03:01 | ERROR | [http-nio-8090-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]:181 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is [UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_SESSION_ID'
 exceptionMessage='Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session hash: 6gdt57/Pbxh3v4/yk9ooOmyQ44B0McQKrtUe7ZU8BMo=
This error usually occurs after a session expires or a user logs out. '
 extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
]
]
] with root cause
com.sforce.soap.enterprise.fault.UnexpectedErrorFault: null
```

.

```
public boolean login() {
    boolean success = false;

    try {
        ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
        if ((proxy!=null) && (!proxy.equals(""))) {
            config.setProxy(proxy, 5150);
        }
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);

        log.info("AuthEndPoint: " + authEndPoint);
        config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);
        config.setRestEndpoint(restEndPoint);

        connection = new EnterpriseConnection(config);
        printUserInfo(config);

        success = true;
        bulkConnection = new BulkConnection(config);

    } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
        log.info("oops~!: ");
        ce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AsyncApiException e) {
        log.info("oops2~!: ");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return success;
}
```

I assume I need to handle that error, but I'm struggling to figure out where to handle it? I'm not seeing the "oops~" log messages in my code, so I assume its happening in the enterpriseconnection or bulk connection? Any tips on how to solve my issue? Still new to rest services. thanks.